# Getters and Setters in javascript. How is the setter implemented? Used in Angular controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, getter

I was reading about getters and setters and this example makes sense to me:

```
var person = {
    firstName: 'Jimmy',
    lastName: 'Smith'
};

Object.defineProperty(person, 'fullName', {
    get: function() {
        return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
    },
    set: function(name) {
        var words = name.split(' ');
        this.firstName = words[0] || '';
        this.lastName = words[1] || '';
    }
});
```

The above is equiv to:

```
var person = {
    firstName: 'Jimmy',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    get fullName() {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    },
    set fullName (name) {
        var words = name.toString().split(' ');
        this.firstName = words[0] || '';
        this.lastName = words[1] || '';
    }
}

person.fullName = 'Jack Franklin';
console.log(person.firstName); // Jack
console.log(person.lastName) // Franklin
```

1. In this code:

   person.fullName = 'Jack Franklin';

   How does the equal sign invoke the setter?
  2.

In this Angular code:

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.phones = data;
  });

  $scope.orderProp = 'age';
});
```

Is a getter used behind the scene when we declare (or call?) the function's arguments in this code:

```
function ($scope, $http) {...}
```

Is the Dependency Injector getting those services based on the name, calling them so that they return something, and setting the return value of those services as the value of those arguments?

Comment: What "equal sign" are you referring to? Which function are you referring to when you say "when we declare... the function's arguments"? Are you referring to the Controller constructor? Yes, the DI is auto-magically determines the service to inject based on the param name. This has nothing to do with getters/setters

Comment: So it gets the service, calls the service, and then....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

***1. How does the equal sign invoke the setter?***

A getter and a setter is a ECMA language construct - it works by invoking the setter function that you defined - see [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1)

***2. Is a getter used behind the scene when we declare (or call?) the function's arguments in this code:***

No, getter is not used. Unless there is an explicit annotation, Angular uses the function's parameter names to look up previously registered services to inject - see [src](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.3/src/auto/injector.js#L99). This is why code minification (which changes the parameter names) breaks that, and why explicit annotation is required using the following two approaches:

```
app.controller("Foo", FooCtrl);

FooCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "$http"];
function FooCtrl($scope, $http){
}
```

```
app.controller("Foo", ["$scope", "$http", FooCtrl]);

function FooCtrl($scope, $http){
}
```

Comment: But once the injector uses the parameter names to look up the service... how does it set the arguments of the function?

Comment: @Jwan622, It invokes the function by passing the service singleton objects

Comment: Okay, let me look up singleton objects and service singleton objects. So that's how the variables are set inside the anonymous function after the dependency declaration?

Comment: @Jwan622, all Angular services are singletons, meaning that there is a single object used, wherever it is injected. When you register a function for a controller or for a service factory - anonymous or not - that function is invoked by Angular, e.g. `controllerFn(serviceA, serviceB)`, with dependencies passed in as parameters.

Comment: Ah cool explanation. So that controller function is called with dependencies passed in parameters which means that somewhere behind the scenes, those arguments are set as the return values of those dependency declarations.

Answer (score 0):

In your `phonecatApp` example it is not using any property accessors. It is is just using the raw properties.

Two rewrite it using property accessors and `controllerAs` syntax it would look like:

```
PhoneListController.$inject = ['$http'];
function PhoneListController($http) {

    var self = this;
    $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
        self._phones = data;
    }):

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'phones', {
        get: function() {
            return self._phones;
        }
    })

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'orderProp', {
        get: function() {
            return 'age';
        }
    }}
}
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListController', PhoneListController);
```

Comment: Though there is no use in rewriting it as properties like that. Instead of using magic in setters to detect changes to properties, AngularJS uses its `$digest` loop and value shadowing.